# Is is possible to determine when a website receives a request (client-side)?

Tags: httprequest, timing

I am making a nodejs program that sends HTTP requests. How could I determine how quickly the request reaches the website?

I can determine the amount of time between sending the request and receiving a response from the server. I'm not sure if I can take this time and just divide it by 2 to determine the amount of time between sending the request and the server receiving the request.

Here is an example of how I would determine the amount of time between sending the request and receiving a response from the server.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url = 'someurl.com';
}

var date1, date2;

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log('Error.');
    } else {
        date2 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(date2-date1);
    }
}

date1 = new Date().getTime();
request(options, callback);
```

This would give me the total time (the amount of time between sending request and receiving response), but not the time that I want (the amount of time between sending request and the website receiving request).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have access to the API, which you are sending your requests.
If that is the case, then you can keep your `date1` and generate `date2` on the server upon receiving the request. Then include that in your response and calculate the difference.
For that synchronise your client<->server timeserver (ntp).

Otherwise you can always keep your approach and divide by 2 as you mentioned.

Hope it helps !